# lost google apps registration code, any idea where i can get a new one?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-workspace

I set up Google Apps but then lost the verification code/file to upload, if I go back to Google and re-apply they say

> This domain has already been registered with Google Apps. Please contact your domain administrator for instructions on using Google Apps with this domain.

But it hasn't been verified, so I'm kind of stuck in a loop.

Comment: How did you loose the code?

Comment: its for a shopify store, i hadent changed the dns on it yet so it was running at mydomain.shopify.com, i set up the google account i said i needed to verify it so i stopped changed the dns so the domain would now be mydomain.com but by the time id done that id closed all the google apps windows and couldnt find the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's codes are unique to a given domain, not a google product, so you should be able to sign the domain up for webmaster tools and verify the domain that way, this will also work for google apps.

You should also be able to login to the google account that you used to sign up and return to the verify screen from the apps dashboard.

Comment: Just took the code from webmaster tools